# TFS 2012 - Web Access change language for all users

Tags: iis, tfs

I´m using a TFS 2012 Update 4 (English).
When I´m using the Web Access, the Website is German becaue Auto-Detection (I´m using a German PC).
But this is confusing because the process template is English and so I´m using a German/English mix system.
I can change the language in my personal TFS profil settings to Englisch. That works.

How can I change the language for every user to english? 
(Because now every day is somebody asking how to change the browser language to English :D )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The default language is taken from browser preferred language. So if in browser language it is set as German and afterwards English the page will be open as German.

To set preferred language see http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Browser%27s-Language

And to set it to everyone you may try group policy changes if applicable.

Hope this helps.

Erez H